# Show that $\varphi : L \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous.

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, compactness

> Let $L,K$ be to compact metric spaces, let $f:K\times L \to \Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Define $\varphi : L \to \Bbb{R}$ as $\varphi(y)=\sup_{x\in K} f(x,y)$. Show that $\varphi$ is continuous.

My attempt;

Let $y\in L$ consider $\left. f \right.|_{K \times \{y\}}:K \times \{y\} \to \Bbb{R}$. Since $\left.f\right.|_{K \times \{y\}}$ is continuous, $K \times \{y\}$ compact, $\left.f\right.|_{K \times \{y\}}$ attains it's maximum say $f(x_0,y)$ and therefore, $\varphi(y)=f(x_0,y)$

Now given $\epsilon >0$ I look for $\delta >0$ such that $d(y_1,y_2)<\delta$ implies $|\varphi(y_1)-\varphi(y_2)| < \epsilon$

So $$|\varphi(y_1)-\varphi(y_2)|=|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)|$$ for some $x_1,x_2 \in K$

Using the continuity of $f$ we have that given $\epsilon$, there exist $\delta_0$ such that $d(y_1,y_2) \leq d((x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)) < \delta_0$ implies $|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)|<\epsilon$. Taking $\delta=\delta_0$ we have that $\varphi$ is continuous.

Is the proof allright? Im not sure in the steps of defining $\left.f\right.|_{K \times \{y\}}$, and saying that the supremum is attained.

Comment: The steps you say you're not sure about seem fine, although it's not clear they're going to lead to a proof. There must be a typo in the sentence starting "Using the continuity...". It's true that $|\phi(y_1)-\phi(y_2)|=|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)|$ for some $x_1,x_2$. But now what? You want to show that $|\phi(y_1)-\phi(y_2)|$ is small if $d(y_1,y_2)$ is small. But to use that inequality to show this you'll need to show that if $d(y_1,y_2)$ is small then so is $d(x_1,x_2)$, and I don't think you're going to be able to do that.

Comment: You might start over. Since $L\times K$ is compact, $f$ is actually _uniformly_ continuous. Now use this: If $A,B\subset\mathbb R$ are such that for every $x\in A$ there exists $y\in B$ with $|x-y|<\epsilon$ and similarly for every $x\in B$ there exists $y\in A$ with $|x-y|<\epsilon$ then $|\sup(A)-\sup(B)|\le\epsilon$. That follows immediately from the definition of the supremum.

Comment: Im using the metric defined on $K \times L$ as, $d((x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2))=max\{d_K(x_1,x_2),d_L(y_1,y_2)\}$

Comment: Actually it's $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))$. But never mind that. The problem is what I said: You don't know that $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))<\delta$ because you don't know anything about $d(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: Oh yeah. I see! You are right!